# Eigenvalues and eigenvector

Tags: mathematical-physics

[image]
From the property of antisymmetric matrices we know that eigenvalue of a antisymmetric matrix is zero or imaginary.
Then solve this.

Comment: Note that homework-like questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community. **We don't answer homework or worked example type questions.**

Comment: See [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Comment: Should be moved to MathSE.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero would be closed as off topic there as well.

Comment: @WrichikBasu Amen to that.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this is the second time today you have basically just demanded an answer. Please show some research in your questions.

Comment: No effort $\Longrightarrow$ Downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give a hint. It helps to think of invariants, like $\det$ and $\text{tr}$. For example, you can compute $\text{tr}(A)$ in two ways: explicitly it gives $\text{tr}(A) = 0$, but you also know that
$$
\text{tr}(A) = \sum_i \lambda_i
$$
where the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. So this puts a constraint on the possible $\lambda_i$. Now consider $\det(A)$, $\text{tr}(A^2)$ etc., and use that the $n_i$ are components of a unit vector.